# SQL Server: Display Column if NOT NULL

Tags: sql-server

I need to create a SQL Server function that accepts a `BillID` as a parameter and returns a table (should only be one row) that lists a `QuotedRate` (REQUIRED) and a `DiscountAmount` OR `DiscountPercent`, but NOT both.

Each `BillID` either has a `DiscountAmount` OR `DiscountPercent`, but NOT both.  One of them is going to be NULL.

How do I return a table that lists a `QuotedRate` along with one of the above mentioned `Discount` columns (whichever one isn't NULL)? Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my code so far:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_ApplyDiscounts(@BillID smallint)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    --IF DiscountAmount IS NOT NULL
    RETURN (SELECT QuotedRate, DiscountAmount
            FROM Bill
            AND BillID = @BillID)

    --ELSE IF DiscountPercent IS NOT NULL

    RETURN (SELECT QuotedRate, DiscountPercent
            FROM Bill
             AND BillID = @BillID)
```

Comment: what happen if  both `DiscountAmount` and `DiscountPercent` are `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

I'm on my mobile, so it's a bit hard to type the code. You just have to use the `coalesce` function. Hence, you need just one single select:

```
RETURN (SELECT QuotedRate, coalesce(DiscountAmount, DiscountPercent) FROM Bill WHERE BillID = @BillID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't SQL, it's logic.

You need to handle

```
No Rate & No Amount
No Rate & Amount
Rate & No Amount
Rate & Amount
```

Your logic should work fine. You can use IF or SELECT statements, you just need to decide what you'll do in each case.

Answer (score 0):

I added a TYPE column so you will know if it's an amount or percent. I think this would be valuable for your case. Also, in case both the amount and percent are nulls this should work too.

```
    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_ApplyDiscounts(@BillID smallint)
    RETURNS 
    @ReturnTable TABLE(
    QuotedRate decimal(8,2),
    Discount decimal (8,2),
    TheType char(1)    
    )

    AS
    BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @ReturnTable (QuotedRate, Discount, TheType)
    SELECT 
    QuotedRate, 
    COALESCE(DiscountAmount, DiscountPercent, '') as Discount,
    CASE 
        WHEN DiscountAmount IS NOT NULL THEN'A' 
        WHEN DiscountPercent IS NOT NULL THEN 'P' 
        ELSE NULL
    END as TheType 
    FROM Bill
    WHERE BillID = @BillID

 RETURN
 END
```